# How to disable auto refinement for select input in algolia instant search

Tags: javascript, vue.js, algolia, gridsome

I have this current code for integrated algolia ais-instant-search that working fine and I want to disable auto refinement on select input to keep the list and when select to return hits for only this selected argument.

```
  <ais-instant-search
:search-client="searchClient"
:index-name="ALGOLIA_INDEX_NAME"
><ais-menu-select :attribute="attribute" :limit="60">
  <select
    class="select rm-raduis-select is-fullwidth"
    slot-scope="{ items, canRefine, refine }"
    :disabled="!canRefine"
    @change="refine($event.currentTarget.value)"
  >
    <option value="">All domain</option>
    <option
      v-for="item in items"
      :key="item.value"
      :value="item.value"
      :selected="item.isRefined"
    >
      {{ item.label }}
    </option>
  </select>
</ais-menu-select>
//hits display ...
```